# JavaFX 8 - How to erase a part of background making it transparent

Tags: javafx-8

I have a Pane and inside it I have a Rectangle shape.
The Pane has a red background. What I want is that, in the part where the rectangle is placed, the background is transparent.

This is the code:

```
Pane pane=new Pane();
pane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.RED, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
Rectangle rect=new Rectangle(50,50,50,50, Color.YELLOW);
pane.getChildren().add(rect);
```

This is the result

[image]

This is what I want

[image]

In the second picture the grey color is the background color of the stage.

I tried to play with the blending mode but I didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish your goal, you could try to use 2 instances of `Rectangle` instead of a `Pane` and a `Rectangle`. By doing so, you could use the static substract method of the `Shape` class to substract the two areas from one another:

```
Shape.substract(Rect_1, Rect_2);
```

As stated by Oracle, the method does exactly what you want to do:

```
public static Shape subtract(Shape shape1,
                             Shape shape2)

Returns a new Shape which is created by subtracting the specified second shape from the first shape.

The operation works with geometric areas occupied by the input shapes. For a single Shape such area includes the area occupied by the fill if the shape has a non-null fill and the area occupied by the stroke if the shape has a non-null stroke. So the area is empty for a shape with null stroke and null fill. The area of an input shape considered by the operation is independent on the type and configuration of the paint used for fill or stroke. Before the final operation the areas of the input shapes are transformed to the parent coordinate space of their respective topmost parent nodes.

The resulting shape will include areas that were contained only in the first shape and not in the second shape.


         shape1       -       shape2       =       result
   +----------------+   +----------------+   +----------------+
   |################|   |################|   |                |
   |##############  |   |  ##############|   |##              |
   |############    |   |    ############|   |####            |
   |##########      |   |      ##########|   |######          |
   |########        |   |        ########|   |########        |
   |######          |   |          ######|   |######          |
   |####            |   |            ####|   |####            |
   |##              |   |              ##|   |##              |
   +----------------+   +----------------+   +----------------+

Parameters:
    shape1 - the first shape
    shape2 - the second shape
Returns:
    the created Shape
```

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html)